# Why does text parameter become object within the function?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, wordpress-gutenberg

I have completed a WordPress Gutenberg tutorial in which I have this function;

```
    var mapSelectToProps = function( select ) {     
        return {
            metaFieldValue: select( 'core/editor' )
            .getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' )
            [ 'sidebar_plugin_meta_block_field' ],
        }
    }
```

I want to modify this code so that instead of the meta field name 'sidebar_plugin_meta_block_field' being hard coded in the function it is passed in as a parameter.

I tried this but got some very odd results:

```
    var meta_key_name = 'sidebar_plugin_meta_block_field';
    console.log("key 1 "+meta_key_name);

    var mapSelectToProps = function( select, meta_key_name ) {

        console.log("key 2 "+meta_key_name);

        return {
            metaFieldValue: select( 'core/editor' )
            .getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' )
            [ { meta_key_name } ],
        }

}
```

In the console the output for key 1 is, as one would expect, a text string - 'sidebar_plugin_meta_block_field'

However, key 2 prints to the console [object Object]

On further investigation this appears to have one attribute - setMetaFieldValue
And this appears to hold a reference to a function - function(){var t;return(t=n.current(r.dispatch,r))[e].apply(t,arguments)}

So my question is why can't I pass into this function a simple text parameter?

All the code lies within a self invoking function

```
( function( wp ) {

    .....

} )( window.wp );
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `{ meta_key_name }` will create an object - it's shorthand for `{ meta_key_name: meta_key_name }`. If you want to keep it a string, then remove `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 0):

You're transforming into an object yourself by placing your variable between the `{}` brackets. Try this

```js
var meta_key_name = 'sidebar_plugin_meta_block_field';
    console.log("key 1 "+meta_key_name);

    var mapSelectToProps = function( select, meta_key_name ) {

        console.log("key 2 "+meta_key_name);

        return {
            metaFieldValue: select( 'core/editor' )
            .getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' )
            [ meta_key_name ], // Remove brackets
        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Evert, unfortunately it has not solved the problem, I am still getting an object within the function. Very strange.

Comment: Can you show where you call the function and which parameters you give to the function? It seems that you give an object to the function itself rather than transforming it inside the function.

Comment: I have part solved the problem. The error is because I am trying to pass parameters into the anonymous function referenced by mapSelectToProps at the point where the function is being defined. I think I need to pass them into the function at the point where it is being called. The problem is this is within the withSelect block and one of the parameters, the select function is not available inside that block. I am sure there must be a way round this.